# why i can't get /post data with authorization using HTTP Interceptor in the angular application and get 403 forbidden?

Tags: angular, http, authorization, postman, angular-http-interceptors

HttpClientInterceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpClientInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private $localStorage: LocalStorageService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>,
            next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.$localStorage.retrieve("authontificationToken");
       if (token) {
      const  clonedRequest = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer `+token)
                            .set('Accept','application/json')
         });
          return next.handle(clonedRequest)
          }
    else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

PostService

```
baseUrl="http://localhost:8080/api/posts";

getPost(permaLink:number):Observable<AddPostPayload>{
    return this.http.get<AddPostPayload>(this.baseUrl+"/get/"+permaLink);
  }
```

PostComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AddPostService } from '../add-post.service';
import { AddPostPayload } from '../add-post/add-post-pay-load';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  permaLink:number;
  post:AddPostPayload;

  constructor(private router:ActivatedRoute,private postService:AddPostService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.params.subscribe(params=>{
      this.permaLink= params['id'];
    }
    );
    this.postService.getPost(this.permaLink).subscribe((data:AddPostPayload)=>{
      
      this.post =data

    });
  }
}
```

When I login with postman with the same path , is work fine , but with the same authorization in the angular app , I got this error !

[Forbidde Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Y1l.png)

[the same Get http with postMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnUmu.png)

Comment: In Postman, You have added 2 Times Bearer in Authorization Para value. Can you remove that one and check please ?

Comment: thanks for replaying my question , i remove one of them and i get forbidden !

Comment: what i can do please ?